# TeamCity Cannot import the following key file: XXX.pfx. The key file may be password protected

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am trying to get TeamCity to Build my VisualStudio2015 c# solution.
However I keep getting this error on TeamCity on the server.

> Cannot import the following key file: XXX.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: YYY

This also occures when I use MSBuild to build the project direct from the commandline on the server.

I have googled and found the answer that suggests running the command "sn -i XXX.pfx YYY"

This command runs sucessfully. However this does not fix the issue and I still get the error.

I have also tried double clicking on XXX.pfx and installing the certificate that way. As with the command line, it says it has been installed but the build still fails for the same reason.

Are there any other things I can try?